# How would i go about making 4 UIImages on UIView Blink or remove based on Timing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I dont have or know the code yet to be able to create this project but basically it would work like a Gauge meter where i have a UIView with a Background and a Test tube image where inside the Test tube image, would have 4 rectangular images stacked on top of eachother

Each having their own properties. The very bottom, the on on top and the middle and the last one on the very top.

My question is, how would i be able to remove the top one based on a NSTimer and so forth till the last Bar image is left ?

I was thinking of using an NSMutableArray to hold the images this way:

```
   NSMutableArray *testTube = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar1"], // 0
                                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar2"], // 1
                                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar3"], // 2
                                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar4"],nil];
```

But aftter this in the IBAction method, i did a:

```
        [testTube removeObjectAtIndex: 3];
```

and it didnt remove it on the app when i clicked the IBAction Button to test it out if i can successfully manipulate the bar4.png

Where am i going wrong ? and as for the timer, it is suppose to remove them one by one in 5 minutes till there is no bar left.

Comment: Anyone have an idea of how i can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

What displays an image on the screen is a `UIImageView` (not a `UIImage`, as your question seems to imply). If you have one of those that you want to remove from the screen, you can do one of the following:

```
[imageView removeFromSuperview];
```

or

```
imageView.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would suggest to handle it:

Set up 4 image views in Interface Builder. Drag the images into your project and set up the image views to line up in your test tube. There is an image property on image views. Enter the name of each image and the image will show up. Make the image view the same size as the image it contains so it doesn't get scaled or stretched.

Then create an IBOutlets for each of your images views by control-dragging from the image view into your view controller's header. Name the top image view imageView1, the next one imageView2, the next imageView3, and the bottom one imageView4.

Define an NSArray property imageViews in your view controller's header. In your viewDidLoad method, add this line:

```
self.imageViews = @[imageView1, imageView2, imageView3, imageView4];
```

Also add a counter instance variable. Let's call it imageIndex;

When your view controller first displays, all 4 image views will be visible.

Finally, you need to start a repeating NSTimer that:

sets the hidden property on the image view at the current index to YES.

The timer method would look something like this:

```
- (void) hideAnImageView: (NSTimer *) theTimer;
{
  self.imageViews[imageIndex].hidden = YES;
  imageIndex++;
  if (imageIndex + 1 > [self.imageViews count] 
    [theTimer invalidate];
}
```

Comment: will definetly try this method, Thnx, will see if it works :)

Comment: I tried this method but i am getting an error with the .hidden = YES; the error says undeclared for HIDDEN, do you have any xcode project example i can follow ?